# Do the quantum mechanical properties of the particles that make up DNA affect mutations in the genome?

Tags: dna, human-genetics, mutations, genomes

Do quantum mechanical properties of particles, such as uncertainty, probability, tunneling, and so on, affect mutations in the genome?

Comment: Not that anyone has ever noticed, but it's not the sort of thing biologists look for as 1. They generally don't have the physics, and 2. There are plenty of macroscopic factors that affect mutations. It is interesting in a more general respect that the celebrated Max Delbrück, a physicist who made early contributions to molecular biology, did so without, as he had hoped, applying any of the new ideas of physics to biology. The supposition that explaining life would involve applying these was incorrect (or at least never realized).

Comment: @David Are you saying that quantum mechanics has no effect on life? But what about quantum biology?

Comment: I am only saying that the mechanisms in genetics are explicable in terms of general chemistry. Quantum biology, as far as I am aware, is mainly concerned with the energetics in systems like photosynthesis, which, although involving biological molecules, are essentially problems in their chemistry. Delbrück did not do quantum biology. However others may be aware of things I am not.

Comment: @David My question was about the processes and mechanisms in genetics that can be explained by quantum mechanics.

Comment: Did you google that question [processes and mechanisms in genetics that can be explained by quantum mechanics]? Because the answer is yes, they affect mutations, on the very first hit (of my search.) Third: [Why does DNA spontaneously mutate? Quantum physics *might* explain.](https://www.livescience.com/quantum-physics-dna-mutations.html). [emphasis mine] So you probably knew the answer already, asking such a very specific yet detail-less question. Oh, and yeah, tunneling and waves and stuff.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I think David's point is that the quantum part is only necessary for understanding the physics of the chemical reactions, not things we ordinarily care about at the level of cells and organisms. Much like how relativity affects every physical interaction, yet if you want to know how long it takes for a ball you drop to hit the floor, Newton is entirely sufficient up to a very small rounding error.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I think these things raise some hackles because there's a tendency for people working in the quantum world to over-extend the value of their work into criticizing those who work with a simpler model or claiming their model is important because it's more accurate or is a "real" explanation or something, and it sounds cool because "quantum" is such a buzz word, yet offers no added real predictive value to models at a higher level that explain the world just fine. It's like if every time a physics TA writes F = ma on the board, a student in the back screams THAT EQUATION IS WRONG

Comment: @BryanKrause - "Not that anyone ever noticed" is a really broad (and possibly discouraging) statement. I'm not usually into physics (including quantum mechanics) much beyond the level you gave an example of. But I am curious by nature, and when someone asks something that takes me by surprise, I usually want to know something about it. Maybe because I don't know very much, especially about boundary pushing by quantum physicists, my hackles didn't get raised. And I find the question suspect. But thanks for the alternative way to look at this.

Comment: @BryanKrause But the question was quite specific: are there mechanisms and processes associated with mutations that can be explained only by quantum mechanics?

Comment: @АрманГаспарян I think what David is trying to get you to think about is what does it mean to be explained "only by quantum mechanics"? Given some chemicals that react in some way, you can measure all sorts of useful things like forward and backward reaction rates, equilibrium concentrations, you can model the effects of temperature and pH, all without knowing a single thing about quantum mechanics. Those numbers, though, do come from some physics. Does that physics matter?

Comment: If you want to understand the physics behind the chemistry, sure, maybe it does. But it doesn't matter to the typical biologist who just needs to know that the chemistry *happens* and in what conditions/how fast/to what extent, etc.

Comment: @BryanKrause I understand what you mean. However, not all processes in nature can be explained by ordinary chemistry (if it is not quantum chemistry).

Comment: @АрманГаспарян Well, electron transport is one area in biology where quantum chemistry is often invoked (as far as I know; this is really outside my area, except that people make bold, unsupported statements about quantum this and quantum that in my area as well :) ), and indeed, it seems like it may be important to understanding *how exactly* electron transport happens, but it certainly isn't necessary to understand the *biology* of electron transport, since you can write the end result in a simple chemical equation and go from there.

Comment: This issue in the philosophy of science is called "reductionism".

Comment: @BryanKrause I'll try to give an example. Quantum tunneling is a purely quantum effect that is not present in classical physics and conventional chemistry. If there was a mutation mechanism that would be caused by quantum tunneling, that would be the answer to my question.

Comment: @АрманГаспарян In biology we very rarely care about the mechanism of a chemical reaction, so there is no distinction. You can easily represent a chemical reaction that occurs due to quantum tunneling without invoking anything quantum at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. (I mean, that's the answer to your question. You didn't ask for specifics.)

From [Quantum and classical effects in DNA point mutations: Watson–Crick tautomerism in AT and GC base pairs](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2021/CP/D0CP05781A#!divAbstract):

> Proton transfer along the hydrogen bonds of DNA can lead to the creation of short-lived, but biologically relevant point mutations that can further lead to gene mutation and, potentially, cancer.

So that's proton tunneling at work in DNA.

This isn't really a new idea. I found one paper theorizing this from the 80's.